# How can I write raw XML to a Label in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c, xml

I am getting a block of XML back from a web service. The client wants to see this raw XML in a label on the page. When I try this:

```
lblXmlReturned.Text = returnedXml;
```

only the text gets displayed, without any of the XML tags. I need to include everything that gets returned from the web service.

This is a trimmed down sample of the XML being returned:

```
<Result Matches="1">
    <VehicleData>
        <Make>Volkswagen</Make>
        <UK_History>false</UK_History>
    </VehicleData>
    <ABI>
        <ABI_Code></ABI_Code>
        <Advisory_Insurance_Group></Advisory_Insurance_Group>
    </ABI>
    <Risk_Indicators>       
        <Change_In_Colour>false</Change_In_Colour>
    </Risk_Indicators>
    <Valuation>
        <Value xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></Value>
    </Valuation>
    <NCAP>
        <Pre_2009></Pre_2009>
    </NCAP>
</Result>
```

What can I do to make this appear on the screen? I noticed that Stack Overflow does a pretty good job of putting the XML on the scren. I checked the source and it's using `<pre>` tags. Is this something that I have have to use?

Answer (score 14):

It would be easier to use a `<asp:Literal />` with it's [`Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) set to `Encode` than to deal with manually encoding Label's Text

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1"  Mode="Encode" />
```

Comment: @p.campbell, what will that do?

Answer (score 8):

You need to [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) the XML first (which escapes special characters like `<` and `>` ):

```
string encodedXml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(xml);
Label1.Text = encodedXml;
```

Surrounding it in `PRE` tags would help preserve formatting, so you could do:

```
string encodedXml = String.Format("<pre>{0}</pre>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(xml));
Label1.Text = encodedXml;
```

As [Bala R mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228883/how-can-i-write-raw-xml-to-a-label-in-asp-net/6228912#6228912), you could just use a `Literal` control with `Mode="Encode"` as this automatically HtmlEncodes any string. However, this would also encode any `PRE` tags you added into the string, which you wouldn't want. You could also use `white-space:pre` in CSS which should do the same thing as the `PRE` tag, I think.