# asp.net label doesn't show xml text in IE

Tags: asp.net, label

I am sitting here in front of a problem with the Internet Explorer. I am developing a ASP.NET Web Forms application.
In my .aspx-File have I a label defined:

```
<asp:Label ID="errorList" runat="server" BorderColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

In this label, I want to write some error statements.
These message has an XML format.

```
errorList.Text = "<xml id='1' error='fatal'/>";
```

But I can't see the text, because the IE don't show a xml text. It is possible to make this possible with an only asp:label on my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to HtmlEncode the XML first (which escapes special characters like < and > ):

```
string encodedXml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(xml);
Label1.Text = encodedXml;
```

source:[How can I write raw XML to a Label in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228883/how-can-i-write-raw-xml-to-a-label-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Try the asp literal something like this

```
<asp:Literal Text="<xml id='1' error='fatal'/>" Mode="Encode" ID="ffff" runat="server" />
```